# Multiple file extensions to include, in recursive-readdir

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to [recursive-readdir](https://github.com/jergason/recursive-readdir#usage) 
to read `.html` and `.js` files only, in a given directory, recursively. However, when I give it an array of `["!*.html", "!*.js"]`, it returns no file.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The documentation says it'll ignore files specified in array, can u paste ur code

Comment: The doc says that you can pass your own ignore function, why not simply use that?

Comment: The ignore function didn't seem to work for me. I return a bool in case of file extension being equal to .html or .js. But it didn't give desired results.

Comment: @kgangadhar yes I am aware of the documentation, and the code doesn't contain anything special. Just `["!*.html", "!*.js"]` replaced in their own example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [brace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Brace_expansion):

```
var recursive = require("recursive-readdir");

recursive("dir1", ["!*.{html,js}"], function(err, files) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(files);
});
```

Comment: I love you. Such an abrupt response =).